# Java resource path inside compiled jar file

Tags: java, jar, resources

I have a problem loading images with getClass().getResource().
Basically it wont load anything because my resources are appearently in a jar file..?
I think the problem is that the resource laoder path is somehow wrong because getClass.getResource is looking for the resources in build/libs/COMPILED_JAR/pathtoresourcefolder when it should be looking for them in build/resources (I think). So appearently the path is wrong somehow but I have no idea why.

What have I done wrong?

My project structure is:

src/main/java -> here are my classes

src/main/resources -> here are my resources

Note: This is probably a duplicate but I couldn't find an answer and I have searched for an hour...

Comment: Really no point in concerning yourself about anythng other than what's in the jar. Please post the output of `jar tf thejar.jar`

Comment: @g00se it lists all the files in my project, the resources I want are included. I don't think anything is missing. Whats interesting is that it put all the resources and classes in the same folder , is that how its supposed to be? https://pastebin.com/QHjcZmH0

Comment: `getResourceAsStream("/com/hhuebner/autogp/symbols/test.png");`

Comment: @g00se Thanks, that worked for one image, but I also want to load a bunch of images dynamically later (all png files that are in a certain folder). How would I do that?  With an InputStream I can't filter for .png and I can't list files of a directory

Comment: You're reading them as resources so you will have put those resources where they are. Therefore you will know their names. If you need to load arbitrary images then you will have to treat them as files, not resources